# Google maps app inflation exception

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I keep getting errors while accessing the maps part of my app 
I included the google play services dependency in my app is there any other library i need to include in it? How do I add the library? All tutorials on the internet use older verions of android studio while I use the latest one.

```
enter code here
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.zeda.TaxiTown/com.zeda.TaxiTown.map}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment"
```

in my android maps application what does this mean?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- This can go anywhere in your layout (see other demos for some examples). -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

JAVA file has this in it
    package com.zeda.TaxiTown;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class map extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: It looks to be an issue with your layout xml file for the Taxitown.map view/fragment.
Can you post that class and the layout file?

Comment: There I've done it for u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using MapView instead and it worked!